# No Internet/Connection Timeout in Windows 10 UWP apps (Edge, Store, Mail) when proxy to localhost is enabled

Tags: windows-10, firewall, localhost

Here's the problem: Windows 10 firewall seems to be hardcoded to block access from managed (UWP) apps to the localhost.

No matter what firewall exception I add, **as soon as I enable the proxy to any localhost port** (Fiddler, lantern, privoxy or any other HTTP proxy running locally), **none of Windows managed apps** can access the Internet. Store, Maps, Mail, Edge, etc. - all get a "**connection timeout**" error.

The **only** solution I found so far is to

1. Turn off the Windows Firewall (in Control Panel - Windows Firewall)
2. Then additionally stop the **MpsSvc** service

Does anyone have a better solution?

**I do need to proxy HTTP via localhost.** (And I would really like to have the Firewall back on)

Here's an excerpt from pfirewall.log:

```
2016-09-04 00:24:20 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53096 8118 52 S 975442834 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:21 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53094 8118 52 S 123465087 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:21 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53096 8118 52 S 975442834 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:22 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53098 8118 52 S 362137210 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:22 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53097 8118 52 S 4172847251 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:22 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53099 8118 52 S 4252811626 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:22 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53101 8118 52 S 1800979757 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:22 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53100 8118 52 S 1685634481 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:23 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53094 8118 48 S 123465087 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
2016-09-04 00:24:23 DROP TCP 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 53096 8118 48 S 975442834 0 65535 - - - RECEIVE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug it's a feature, called network isolation. It was introduced in Windows 8 (where UWP apps were called Windows Runtime apps).

> For security reasons, a UWP app that is installed in the standard
> manner is not allowed to make network calls to the device it is
> installed on.

More details [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn640582.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#debugging-options).

The article [*How to allow loopback for Windows Runtime apps*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780593.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) talks about using the CheckNetIsolation Windows tool to enable loopback access per application:

```
CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt -s

CheckNetIsolation.exe LoopbackExempt –a –p=S-1-15-2-4125766819-3228448775-2449327860-2490758337-1264241865-3581724871-2122349299
```

There are also GUI tools such as [**Enable Loopback Utility**](https://telerik-fiddler.s3.amazonaws.com/fiddler/addons/enableloopbackutility.exe) and [Loopback Exemption Manager](https://github.com/tiagonmas/Windows-Loopback-Exemption-Manager) which make this task easier:

[image: Enable Loopback Utility]

Comment: Do you know if this is still possible when running the windows 10 anniversary update?

Comment: Yes it's still work

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by reading this link: https://appuals.com/windows-10-creators-update-no-internet-connection-fix/

That it what I did:

1. I disabled and then re-enabled **all** the computer’s network connections in "Network & Internet settings" > "Change Adapter options"
2. On an Administrator Command Prompt I run the following commands

   `netsh winsock reset
   netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
   netsh int ip reset
   ipconfig /release
   ipconfig /renew
   ipconfig /flushdns`
3. I fully shutdown and then restarted the computer